# Retrieve List of Layout/View's attributes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm working on a small learning-tool project that has several different views displayed in various fragments. What I'd like to do is when the user selects a layout or view (e.g. TextView), a dialog pops up that shows all its available attributes (e.g. android:layout_width, android:layout_height, android:focusable, etc). Rather than going through each layout/view and manually typing the attributes in a file or class, I was hoping there was a way to programmatically get the attributes. Currently, I just have a JSON file I'm reading from, but it's becoming extremely tedious. An issue also arises with different API versions.

[image]
[image]

Just to get an idea of what I'm currently dealing with, here's my JSON file:

```
{
  "LayoutParams": [
    "android:layout_height",
    "android:layout_width"
  ],

  "MarginLayoutParams": [
    "android:layout_margin",
    "android:layout_marginBottom",
    "android:layout_marginEnd",
    "android:layout_marginHorizontal",
    "android:layout_marginLeft",
    "android:layout_marginRight",
    "android:layout_marginStart",
    "android:layout_marginTop",
    "android:layout_marginVertical"
  ],

  "RelativeLayout": {
    "inherited_properties": [
      "MarginLayoutParams",
      "LayoutParams"
    ],
    "primary_properties": [{
        "android:gravity": ["bottom", "center", "center_horizontal", "center_vertical", "clip_horizontal", "clip_vertical", "end", "fill", "fill_horizontal", "fill_vertical", "left", "right", "start", "top"],
        "android:ignoreGravity": [""],
        "android:layout_above": [],
        "android:layout_alignBaseline": [],
        "android:layout_alignBottom ": [],
        "android:layout_alignEnd": [],
        "android:layout_alignLeft": [],
        "android:layout_alignParentBottom": [],
        "android:layout_alignParentEnd": [],
        "android:layout_alignParentLeft": [],
        "android:layout_alignParentRight": [],
        "android:layout_alignParentStart": [],
        "android:layout_alignParentTop": [],
        "android:layout_alignRight": [],
        "android:layout_alignStart": [],
        "android:layout_alignTop": [],
        "android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing": [],
        "android:layout_below": [],
        "android:layout_centerHorizontal": [],
        "android:layout_centerInParent": [],
        "android:layout_centerVertical": [],
        "android:layout_toEndOf": [],
        "android:layout_toLeftOf": [],
        "android:layout_toRightOf": [],
        "android:layout_toStartOf": []
      }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract them from [R.stylable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html).

AFAIK, there's no XML schema or DTD defined, so `R.stylable` might be your only choice.

Comment: It looks like it would be about sixes then between using R.stylable vs manually creating the JSON file, unless I'm not understanding how to use R.stylable properly